# Cox proportional model w/ multiple failures for same subjects

Tags: statistics, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a data set that I'm trying to model using survival analysis, specifically cox proportional hazard models. The data has patient IDs and several attributes about the patients (including time till failure). Due to the nature of the data, a patient could fail and then fail again later several times. This means that some of the patients are repeated in the data due to multiple failures. However, patients aren't all repeated and when they are, they aren't all repeated the same number of times.

My question is: how should this be handled in cox proportional hazard modeling?

Should each instance be treated as independent (I don't think that would make too much sense)?

Should the patient data be aggregated in some way so that each patient is being included once in the model while still utilizing his/her data from the multiple failures?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer to how to use CoxPH is basically ... don't. The other method that would allow modeling is Poisson regression. It would allow the number of failures to be the outcome and further would allow the total time of observation to be an offset on the RHS of the formula. You didn't include a programming environment so code wouldn't be appropriate, but this can be done in any of hte major statistical packages. I think overall this would be more appropriate on CrossValidated.com

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave it a shot on crossvalidated